# Dynamic CRM 2013: Unable to show list of my custom entity after i've created it

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have configured a custom entity with two filed and visibility: business unit / parent child and without other relations ship.

I've setup permission of a customer Role (ROLEA) to use new entity (Business unit / parent child permission).

I've loggen in with an user (USERA) belong that Role (ROLEA) and I can create a new entity but when i come back to the list it's empty.

I've loggen in with an administrator user and i see the new record.
The new record has owner USERA.

What I miss ?, 
thanks Ale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soveld!

After hours of trials I've try to remove the user USERA from the security role (ROLEA) and add again to the same security role.

After that, login with USERA and in the list of new entities was correctly displayed my data.

Ok, I've starter with a couple of users but if i've have thoussnd of users? is there a method to refresh Security Role membership ?